# Getting next two words from a given word in string with words containing non alphanumeric characters as well

Tags: java, string

I have a `String` as below:

```
String str = "This is something Total Toys (RED) 300,000.00 (49,999.00) This is something";
```

Input from user would be a `keyword` `String` viz. `Total Toys (RED)`

I can get the index of the keyword using `str.indexOf(keyword);`

I can also get the start of the next word by adding length of keyword `String` to above index.

However, how can I get the next two tokens after the keyword in given String which are the values I want?

```
if(str.contains(keyWord)){
 String Value1 = // what should come here such that value1 is 300,000.00 which is first token after keyword string?
 String Value2 = // what should come here such that value2 is (49,999.00) which is second token after keyword string?
}
```

Context : Read a PDF using PDFBox. The keyword above is the header in first column of a table in the PDF and the next two tokens I want to read are the values in the next two columns on the same row in this table.

Comment: Look for the 2nd space or end of line after the index of keyword you just found in the string.

Comment: @chuthan20: The keyword String is dynamic and I will not have knowledge about the number of words present in the keyword String which in above example is 2 bases on which you are commenting!

Comment: Would you always have 2 words after the keyword you are searching for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) to do this.  This will work for all instances of the keyword that are followed by two tokens, if the keyword is not followed by two tokens, it won't match; however, this is easily adaptable, so please state if you want to match in cases where 0 or 1 tokens follow the keyword.

```
String regex = "(?i)%s\\s+([\\S]+)\\s+([\\S]+)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(String.format(regex, Pattern.quote(keyword))).matcher(str);

while (m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

In you example, `%s` in `regex` would be replaced by `"Total Toys"`, giving:

> 300,000.00
>  49,999.00

`(?i)` means case-insensitive
`\\s` means whitespace
`\\S` means non-whitespace
`[...]` is a [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html)
`+` means 1 or more
`(...)` is a capturing group

**EDIT**:
If you want to use a keyword with special characters intrinsic to regular expressions, then you need to use `Pattern.quote()`.  For example, in regex, `(` and `)` are special characters, so a keyword with them will result in an incorrect regex.  `Pattern.quote()` interprets them as raw characters, so they will be escaped in the regex, ie changed to `\\(` and `\\)`.

If you want three groups, use this:

```
String regex = "%s\\s+([\\S]+)\\s+([\\S]+)(?:\\s+([\\S]+))?";
```

NB: If only two groups follow, group(3) will be `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and comments Steve.. However, if in the string the keyword and the two tokes are like "TOTAL TOYS (ONLY) (1234) (5678)" -- in this case Matcher m is not able to match the keyword in the input String... Do I need to modify something for case with opening closing braces ?

Comment: @Vicky Do you just mean that you want it to be case insensitive?  If so, the above should match `(ONLY)` and `(1234)`, right?

Comment: :Yes.. But its not getting matched.. The call while (m.find()) is returning without going inside!

Comment: Keyword string is "Total Toys (RED)" while the input string is "This is something Total Toys (RED) (123) (456) This is something"

Comment: @Vicky This should definitely work now.  Sorry, didn't realize that that was an acceptable input, nor that you wanted case-insensitivity.  Good luck.

Comment: At one point in the usecase, I want to get first and third token after the keyword. But m.group(3) inside the m.find() while loop is returning IndexOutOfBoundsException!

Comment: @Vicky That's because there is no third group.  You did not specify that you wanted 3 captures...

Comment: Thanks! I must learn regular expressions.. best book suggestions for starters :) ?

Comment: @Vicky Check out this [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).  It's the best I've come across.  There are a ton of sections on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
String remainingPart= str.substring(str.indexOf(keyWord)+keyWord.length());
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(remainingPart);
if(st.hasMoreTokens()){
   Value1=st.nextToken();
}
if(st.hasMoreTokens()){
   Value2=st.nextToken();
}
```

Comment: What if there are multiple instances of the keyword?  Are we supposed to take `Value1` even if value 2 does not exist?

Comment: I guess the first instance of the keyword is what matters. As for the values i have no idea :) depends on what you need this code to do

Comment: StringTokenizer seems to be a legacy class as per official docs

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

String str = "This is something Total Toys 300,000.00 49,999.00 This is something";

```
if(str.contains(keyWord)) {
 String splitLine = str.split(keyword)[1];
 String tokens[] = splitLine.split(" ");
 String Value1 =  tokens[1];
 String Value2 = tokens[2];
}
```

Comment: Be careful. This may not work if the keyword is present more than once in the string

Answer (score -1):

Here is something that works given what you have provided:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  String search = "Total Toys";
  String str = "This is something Total Toys 300,000.00 49,999.00 This is something";
  int index = str.indexOf(search);
  index += search.length();
  String[] tokens = str.substring(index, str.length()).trim().split(" ");
  String val1 = tokens[0];
  String val2 = tokens[1];
  System.out.println("Val1: " + val1 + ", Val2: " + val2);
}
```

Output:

```
Val1: 300,000.00, Val2: 49,999.00
```

Comment: This fails for several different inputs.  Think about it.

Comment: The caveat "something that works given what you have provided" allows the OP to make their own decision based on other inputs. My solution works given what was provided.

Comment: It works on one base case that it's supposed to work on.  That's like saying that you developed a method for division that doesn't account for diving by 0, since that was never given in the example inputs...what if there aren't two tokens following the keyword?  what if there are multiple instances of the keyword?